# Convert text under a heading into an org-table

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I am using spacemacs. I've written my shortcuts in an org file to not forget them. It has a structure of Description: key, then I go to the next line and enter the next command.
For example

*** Latex

Preview at point: SPC m p p 
Jump to begin or the end of the environment: %
Use macro: C-c RET 
Create environment: C-c C-e or SPC m e

It occured to me, that using an org-table for this would fit quite nicely. By now I have quite some headings with corresponding shortcuts. Is there an elegant fast way to convert my records under a certain heading/tree in an org-table format, so that the text before ":" goes into a first column of a table and the text after ":" in a second column with one table row dedicated for each entry pair? Some custom function defined via defun?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I discovered an alternative efficient way for me. I just used `M-x query-replace` (`M-x %`) to replace all `:` (colons) by `,` (comma). Afterwards I could apply the convertion command `C-c |` to retain the structure I had. The answer of allsOrts answers it partially, but doesn't mention the trick, that comma can be used for separation to get the 2 columns structure in this case (I am not sure what is meant under replacing colon with a tab).

Answer (score 0):

For the `:`, a simple `M-x query-replace` will quickly get you the `|` between the two columns. For the `|` at the beginning and end, `M-x query-replace-regexp` should do:

- replace `^` with `|` for the beginning of the line
- replace `$` with `|` for the end of the line

Once you've got all the `|` inserted, pressing tab anywhere in the table will line up all the columns.

Comment: From `*** Latex` in the question I concluded that he has several subsections with major modes in his subtree. Therefore, I suggested an alternative approach treating all key descriptions in the subtree at once. (Not only the ones for one major-mode.)

Answer (score 0):

The following approach works for the full subtree describing the key-bindings for all major-modes at once (if the structure of your document is really as you indicated in the question):

1. narrow to the subtree in question: <kbd>C-x n s</kbd>
2. Type <kbd>C-<home></kbd> to go to the beginning of buffer.
3. query replace with <kbd>M-C-%</kbd> `^\([[:alnum:] ]+\):\( .*\)$` <kbd>RET</kbd> `|\1|\2|` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

In the 2nd item I assume that your descriptions only contain alphanumeric characters and spaces.

Comment: I like the approach with regexp exchange, as I understand, you divide into 1 group until : and second group after : by using curvy braces. Unfortunately this command doesn't find anything to replace, maybe the first expression is not correct?

Answer (score 0):

I often use `(C-c |)` to convert tab separated areas, so you could perhaps simply replace the colon character with a tab and use that.

Or wrap some elisp around `(org-table-convert-region BEG0 END0 &optional SEPARATOR)`

Initially I wondered if what you really want is to use the powerful (and I mean to learn this for myself still) [Emacs Org's Column View](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-column-view-tutorial.html), `org-columns`(`C-c C-x C-c`).  But having read it again I see that is not appropriate at all to this need.

Comment: Not what I asked for, still a nice command to discover though.